# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE non-index columns

Tags: python, mysql

I have a code that is updating a few mySQL tables with the data that is coming from a Sybase database. The table structures are exactly the same.
Since the number of tables may increase in the future, I wrote a Python script that loops over an array of table names, and based on the number of columns in each of those tables, the insert statement dynamically changes:

```
'''insert into databaseName.{} ({}) values ({})'''.format(table, columns, parameters)
```

as you can see, the value parameters are not hardcoded, which has caused this problem where I can't modify this query to do an "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE".

for example, the insert statement may look like:

```
insert into databaseName.table_foo (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
```

or

```
insert into databaseName.table_bar (col1,col2,col3) values (%s,%s,%s)
```

how can I use "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" in here to update non-index columns with their corresponding non-index values?

I can update this question by including more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is this:

```
'''replace into databaseName.{} ({}) values ({})'''.format(table, columns, parameters)
```

This works similarly to IODKU, in that if the values conflict with a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY of the table, it replaces the row, overwriting the other columns, instead of causing a duplicate key error.

The difference is that REPLACE does a DELETE of the old row followed by an INSERT of the new row. Whereas IODKU does either an INSERT or an UPDATE. We know this because if you create triggers on the table, you'll see which triggers are activated.

Anyway, using REPLACE would make your task a lot simpler in this case.

If you must use IODKU, you would need to add more syntax after the `update` at the end. Unfortunately, there is no syntax for "assign all the columns respectively to the new row's values." You must assign them individually.

For MySQL 8.0.19 or later use this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (?,?,?) AS new
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a = new.a, b = new.b, c = new.c;
```

In earlier MySQL, use this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (?,?,?)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a = VALUES(a), b = VALUES(b), c = VALUES(c);
```